# Should I use the DeviceContext functions to input in the Pipeline in loop or by creation?

Tags: c++, directx-11

Hey guys should I use the DeviceContext functions like IASetVertexBuffers, IASetPrimitiveTopology, VSSetShader by creation like

```
void init() {
  //create window and stuff
  devicecontext->IASetVertexBuffers(...);
}

void draw() {
  //draw
}
```

or in loop like

```
void init() {
  //create window and stuff
}

void draw() {
  devicecontext->IASetVertexBuffers(...);
  //draw
}
```

and here is my code that im actually using

```
void ARenderer::Draw(AMesh * mesh, AShader* shader)
{
    ARenderer::SetViewport(currentviewport);
    ARenderer::ApplyShader(shader);


    ///Drawing 
    uint32_t stride = sizeof(AVertex);
    uint32_t offset = 0;

    dxmanager->DeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, mesh->GetBuffer().GetAddressOf(), &stride, &offset);
    dxmanager->DeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(static_cast<D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY>(mesh->GetPrimitive()));
    dxmanager->DeviceContext->Draw(mesh->GetVertexCount(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that you will want to draw more than one object or thing in your application, it means you will have to call them several times per frame already, so initialization time is not an option.

It is safer for you to always set all the necessary states prior to a draw until it manifests performance issues in your application. That usually never happen in small applications. Once you are done with features and correctness, you can try to be smarter on sending things, not before.